# Strange error caused by option addition in an HTML dropdown list

Tags: html

This HTML code block, which forms a table with a dropdown list as an element works ok.

```
<table border="0" summary="Error Models">
<tr>
<th>Ambiguity Resolution Options</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Strategy: 
<select name="strategy">
   <option value="off">OFF</option>
   <option value="float">Float</option>
   <option value="instantaneous">Instantaneous</option>

</select>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

When I try to add a "Fix-and-Hold" option into this dropdown list, as follows:

```
<option value="fix-and-hold">Fix-and-Hold</option>
```

I get an error message, which persists even when i changed the "fix-and-hold" value.

As far as I know, there are no restrictions in the possible values that can assigned in value parameter. So, what causes this error?

I use the [Tryit (W3schools)](http://www.w3schools.com) editor to code HTML for test purposes, as i don't have an HTML framework capable of displaying pages without publishing them at this moment.

Comment: And what is the error? I actually doubt that the browser will throw an error regarding anything HTML related. A better to tool to test stuff is http://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: HTML doesn't throw errors. What are you using to publish the HTML and what is the error?

Comment: @WhiteElephant: I use the Tryit editor (from W3C schools page), so it doesn't need to publish the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect there's something dynamic going on, either via javascript, server-side, or in your IDE itself.

See the html snippet working on jsfiddle.net here: http://jsfiddle.net/WUjhu/

In general, though, just because one browser will run it doesn't mean much, because browsers are very tolerant of horribly malformed html, so what you want to do with your html when you encounter a problem is run in through the validator here: http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Of course, when putting that code through the validator, there are no errors, because it's perfectly valid html, as long as only that html is involved.  To me, that implies that your editor/previewer is failing you.  Check the doctype and surrounding code to see what it adds that could be breaking stuff, otherwise get a better editor.

Comment: I don't use any JS until now in my code.

Comment: It is, of course, best to post any error message you get along with your code, that'll help in debugging.  But you mention the w3schools try-it-editor.  First off, w3schools isn't always reliable in various ways, so be aware of that.  Running their try-it-editor on their website is likely to introduce extra problems just from the doctype or javascript on their page, or additional restrictions.  There are better places (jsfiddle.net, for example, depending on what you're doing) to actually try out your code.

Comment: Getting a better editor is the best option. One should not expect much from a w3schools product (see http://w3fools.com). You can simply use any text editor, like Notepad++, to create an HTML document, and various browsers to view it locally.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. W3 validator has found some errors in my code, but ain't no message refers to "fix-and-hold" value.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: I used W3 editor just because shows the page directly, without the need of publishing.

Comment: Problem solved when i add a directive for utf8 encoding.

Comment: @Kapoios: Has Jukka said, you don't have to "publish" an HTML document just to view it. Create the document with your favourite text editor, save it and open it with your browser. Web browsers can also read local files.

Comment: @Kapoios that could do it, I don't doubt.  The thing other than encoding to be careful of is doctype.  These days, there's no reason to ever use anything other than the html5 doctype, but if it's -not- present, any weird thing could happen.